# git (CLI) won't let me switch branches

Tags: git, checkout

I have two branches in the local repository:

```
tools@secmgrprd02:~/src/dev/auth-monitoring$ git branch
  dev-mar-21
* master
```

as you see I am on master (I swapped back to check something).

when I try to switch back to the dev branch I get:

```
tools@secmgrprd02:~/src/dev/auth-monitoring$ git checkout -b dev-mar-21
fatal: A branch named 'dev-mar-21' already exists.
```

As usual I am clearly missing something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-b` option is a request to first create a new branch before switching to it. You want to switch to an *existing* branch, so `-b` is not needed.

```
git checkout dev-mar-21
```